# Sinon with PhantomXHR - Window.sinon is undefined

Tags: xmlhttprequest, phantomjs, casperjs, sinon, slimerjs

I am using CasperJS along with PhantomXHR. When I run the code in webkit version I can able to mock the response but the same script is not working in Firefox using --engine= slimerjs. It launches the Firefox browser and shows the Page error as window.sinon is undefined. Any solution to get rid of this issue. Are PhantomXHR + sinon will support with slimerjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much struggle i have found that gloabl variable assigned to window is causing the issue.Just use sinon instead of window.sinon in phantomxhr